# Differentiate 0x and 0x0000 varbinary columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary

I have a table with a column of datatype `VARBINARY(252)`. Some of the rows have a **0x** value and most of them have a **0x0000000.....** value in this `VARBINARY` column.

So how do I write a `SELECT` statement to fetch the rows with **0x** value

-and-

a `SELECT` statement to fetch the rows with a **0x0000000.....** value?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not clear but it seems [datalength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a part of your solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm forgetting something, can't you just say `where col = 0x`?

Comment: @shawnt00: Unfortunately no. That was my first try but it fetches both 0x and 0x00000 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Smor, I think I figured out the answer to my question. The value 252 is hard-coded because that is the max length of my datatype.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Col1] = 0x
    AND DATALENGTH([Col1]) <> 252
```